Preserve x-axis breaks and element_markdown specs on each facet in ggplot2 with facet_wrap and free_x
Say I have the final_df data frame in the MWE below, and I make the plot below it, using a custom scale_x_continuous and element_markdown from ggtext.
myseq <- "AGAATATTATACATTCATCT"
set.seed(123)
mydata <- data.frame(time=1:100, value=rnorm(100, mean=10, sd=2))
indices <- seq(5, 100, length.out=20)
seqsplit <- unlist(strsplit(myseq, ""))
ind_df <- data.frame(call=seqsplit, time=indices)
final_df <- dplyr::left_join(mydata, ind_df, by="time")
xcolors <- ifelse(seqsplit=="A", "green", ifelse(seqsplit=="C", "blue", ifelse(seqsplit=="G", "black", "red")))
P <- ggplot2::ggplot(final_df, ggplot2::aes(x=time, y=value)) +
  ggplot2::geom_line(linewidth=0.5) +
  ggplot2::scale_x_continuous(breaks=indices, labels=seqsplit) +
  ggplot2::theme_light() +
  ggplot2::theme(axis.title.x=ggplot2::element_blank(),
                 axis.text.x=ggtext::element_markdown(face="bold", color=xcolors))
grDevices::pdf(file="test.pdf", height=3, width=10)
print(P)
grDevices::dev.off()


Now I have a few other similar sequences and their data stored in a list, like mylist in the MWE below.
I want to make a faceted plot where each facet corresponds to a sequence, and each plot in the facet is identical to the individual example plot above, preserving custom breaks and labels in each x-axis, as well as the letter colors.
How can I accomplish that? This is where I am at (with the problematic lines commented out):
mylist <- list()
mylist[["ID1"]][["sequence"]] <- "AGAATATTATACATTCATCT"
mylist[["ID2"]][["sequence"]] <- "GCTAGCGTTTAGTTT"
mylist[["ID3"]][["sequence"]] <- "AACCCTTTAGTA"
set.seed(123)
mylist[["ID1"]][["data"]] <- data.frame(time=1:100, value=rnorm(100, mean=10, sd=2))
mylist[["ID2"]][["data"]] <- data.frame(time=1:60, value=rnorm(60, mean=10, sd=2))
mylist[["ID3"]][["data"]] <- data.frame(time=1:120, value=rnorm(120, mean=10, sd=2))
mylist[["ID1"]][["indices"]] <- seq(5, 100, length.out=20)
mylist[["ID2"]][["indices"]] <- seq(4, 60, length.out=15)
mylist[["ID3"]][["indices"]] <- seq(10, 120, length.out=12)
all_df <- NULL
for (id in names(mylist)){
  seqsplit <- unlist(strsplit(mylist[[id]][["sequence"]], ""))
  ind_df <- data.frame(call=seqsplit, time=mylist[[id]][["indices"]])
  finaldf <- dplyr::left_join(mylist[[id]][["data"]], ind_df, by="time")
  finaldf$id <- id
  xcolors <- ifelse(seqsplit=="A", "green", ifelse(seqsplit=="C", "blue", ifelse(seqsplit=="G", "black", "red")))
  all_df <- rbind(all_df, finaldf)
}
P <- ggplot2::ggplot(all_df, ggplot2::aes(x=time, y=value)) +
  ggplot2::geom_line(linewidth=0.5) +
  #ggplot2::scale_x_continuous(breaks=indices, labels=seqsplit) + #HOW?
  ggplot2::theme_light() +
  ggplot2::facet_wrap(~id,  ncol=1, scales="free_x", strip.position="left")
  #ggplot2::theme(axis.title.x=ggplot2::element_blank(),
  #               axis.text.x=ggtext::element_markdown(face="bold", color=xcolors)) #HOW?
grDevices::pdf(file="test_all.pdf", height=6, width=10)
print(P)
grDevices::dev.off()



Here is one possible option which uses ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales to individually set the scale for each facet (aka the breaks and labels) and instead of passing a vector of colors via the theme() uses ggtexts capabilities to style text using some HTML and CSS, i.e. I add the color directly to the label:
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)
library(ggh4x)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(glue)

scale_x <- purrr::map(mylist, \(x) {
  indices <- x$indices
  seqsplit <- unlist(strsplit(x$sequence, ""))
  colors <- dplyr::case_match(
    seqsplit,
    "A" ~ "green",
    "C" ~ "blue",
    "G" ~ "black",
    .default = "red"
  )
  labels <- glue::glue(
    "<span style='color: {colors}'>{seqsplit}</span>"
  )
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = indices, labels = labels
  )
})

ggplot2::ggplot(all_df, ggplot2::aes(x = time, y = value)) +
  ggplot2::geom_line(linewidth = 0.5) +
  ggplot2::theme_light() +
  ggplot2::facet_wrap(~id,
    ncol = 1,
    scales = "free_x", strip.position = "left"
  ) +
  ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales(
    x = scale_x
  ) +
  ggplot2::theme(
    axis.title.x = ggplot2::element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = ggtext::element_markdown(face = "bold")
  )



hmmm was hoping there would be a ggplot2 option... at this point might just be easier to use plot_grid() from cowplot; just make the plots individually and combine them after
